# Values not showing in childcomptwo component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

childoneComp.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="accListCon">
  <aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:ApplicationEvent"/>
  <lightning:button label="App Button" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.clickebent}" />
</aura:component>
```

childoneCompcontroller.js

```
({
    clickebent : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getAccRec");

        action.setCallback(this, function(res){
            var results = res.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.accVar", results);

            var appeventtest = $A.get("e.c:ApplicationEvent");
            //var JSONStr = JSON.stringify(results); 
            appeventtest.setParams({
                "msg" : results
            });
            appeventtest.fire();
            component.set("v.accVar", results);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);


    } })
```

childtwocomp.cmp

```
<aura:component >

  <aura:attribute name="accVars" type="sObject" />

    <aura:handler event="c:ApplicationEvent" action="{!c.actiontwocompo}" />
     <h1>hello222</h1>
    {!v.accVars}
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accVars}" var="acc">
      {!acc.Name}
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

childtwocompcontroller.js

```
({
    actiontwocompo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var msgge = event.getParams();
        component.set("v.accVars", msgge);
        console.log("value ::::"+JSON.stringify(msgge));
    }
})
```

I can see the value in `console.log("value ::::"+JSON.stringify(msgge));` but the values are not showing in childtwocomp.

Event

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="msg" type="sObject"/>
</aura:event>
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `accVars` is typed as an `sObject`. `event.getParams()` does not return an `sObject`; its value is a map *containing* what we presume is an sObject (since you haven't shown the Apex code involved):

```
        appeventtest.setParams({
            "msg" : results
        });
```

You'd need to extract the `msg` value from the result of `getParams()` for this code to make sense.